# What do you call (the fact that languages are not always one-to-one in their labellings)?

Tags: terminology, comparative-linguistics

Based on [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/918/why-isnt-good-morning-buenas-ma%C3%B1anas). There is no reason that there should be a ["Good" + "morning"] in Spanish any more than there is a ["Good" + "days"] in English. I notice that in language-learners, there is an undue assumption that phrases or words in the target language will correspond one-to-one with such in the destination language, so long as idioms are excluded. Through analogy, I might get rid of this assumption in others by explaining what a calque is, inventing an awkward calque, and hoping it clicks. That is not direct enough. This could be explained simpler. In the universe of calques and non-calques-that-are-not-idioms, what is a non-calque-... called?